# Regex to match exactly one alpha string with periods allowed inside of ${}

Tags: regex

As the title says, I'm trying to write a regex that ensures that a String contains exactly something following this pattern: ${one.two.three.four} where there can be any number of  followed by a , followed by another . So,

- The whole string needs to be wrapped with ${}
- The content inside of the ${} has to start with an alpha string followed by a
- Any alpha string that has a . following it has to have another alpha string following it.

I'm using it to write almost a poor-mans SPEL expression, but for getting properties only. So, it might be something like ${user.name} or ${user.name.first}, etc.

Comment: What is alpha string? Are there beta strings of some kind as well?

Comment: just meant Alphabetical, so just letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `^\${(?:[A-z]+\.?)+}$`

Improved to: `^\${[A-z]+(?:\.[A-z]+)*}$` which will prevent matching ${one.}

And here's a link to regex101 that explains the regex and shows it matching the test strings you gave

https://regex101.com/r/YnYP7P/4

Comment: Thanks, that got me super close! I had to modify it to ^\${(?:([A-z]+\.[A-z]+)+?)+}$ so it wouldn't match, for example ${one.}

Comment: I modified the regex to fix that issue, enjoy!